# Arrays and Lists in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, dynamic-arrays

How would you develop the following types of lists in C++?

a.  The list’s size is known at compile time?

b.  The list’s size is determined once at runtime but it is fixed thereafter?

c.  The list’s size must be changeable during runtime and you are not allowed to use 
vectors?

Comment: Important questions, what were your first thoughts on the answers?  We can help improve them if they need it.

Comment: Seems like homework, try looking into the following things.

A) Standard Array
B) Pointer of objects
C) Linked list

Comment: For a, we can directly input size like, int intArray[5].

For b, may be we can ask user to input size and then allocate the memory.

For c, I've no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a. The list’s size is known at compile time?`  Any normal static array.

`b. The list’s size is determined once at runtime but it is fixed thereafter?` A dynamic array. Initialized with using a variable as size.

`c. The list’s size must be changeable during runtime and you are not allowed to use vectors?`  I guess an arraylist or a linked list or anything along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

> How would you develop the following types of lists in C++?
>
> a. The list’s size is known at compile time?

Use `std::array`

---

> b. The list’s size is determined once at runtime but it is fixed thereafter?

Use `std::vector`.

---

> c. The list’s size must be changeable during runtime and you are not allowed to use vectors?

Resign, but if you are contractually obligated to work for some time after resigning, then use a `std::deque`.

Comment: Why do we need std::vector? What's wrong with just regularly newing an array?

Comment: I do not think so that the size of vector is fixed in C++. It expands automatically as you add elements to a vector. Isn't this the case?

Comment: @Daniel: memory management is difficult to get right, in particular eventual deallocation, but also e.g. for resizing. `std::vector` automates all that in a safe and transparent way. in addition to the importance of using well-tested, safe, efficient abstractions, being *not allowed* to use them is more than enough reason to resign: it's no good working for incompetents or those sabotaging your work.

Comment: @user3813179 That is correct. There is no reason to choose a vector for a fixed-size list.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question is specifically asking about a list that _will not_ need to be resized.

Comment: @Daniel: so? i'm sorry i do not understand your question.

Comment: Also, you've never had a case in your work where you wanted to have a variable-length list? It's not all that uncommon.

Comment: @Daniel But then how would you determine the size of list during runtime?

Comment: The main benefit of `std::vector` is that it is automatically dynamically resized without the programmer having to think about buffer sizes. In this example, we don't need any such functionality. A vanilla array will give us everything we need.

Comment: @user3813179 That depends on your application. But when you created the fixed-size array, presumably you knew what size to create it at some point. Just store it.

Comment: @Daniel: standard C++ doesn't support variable length vanilla arrays. C99 does, and g++ does as a language extension. you pay for that in non-portability, unsafety and inefficiency, which price is simply too high for most.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf YOU DON'T NEED VARIABLE LENGTH ARRAYS. That's what the question says! The size is determined at runtime and then fixed!

Comment: please don't shout. instead, code up what you think would be a good solution. then present that in an answer to the question. it will either be non-portable or involve manual dynamic allocation. either way, bad.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't understand what the problem with manual dynamic allocation is? You have to remember to delete it?\

Comment: @Daniel: you have to remember to deallocate exactly once. to do that the code needs to be exception safe and somehow know what part of it is responsible for doing that. both parts are difficult to get right. in addition you're duplicating code patterns. each manual duplication of a pattern is an invitation to bugs and a possibility of duplicating bugs, especially when the code is later maintained.

Answer (score 0):

- a) A compile-time list of types http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/list.html or Boost.Fusion with a `boost::fusion::vector`
- b) A container that stores objects with number of elements
- c) linked-list